# Eliminar registro 24hrs despues de creado

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

como hago para que los registros de una tabla de mi base de datos MySql, se eliminen cada 24 horas automáticamente sin hacer uso de cronjobs.

Pd: uso php.

Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tienes acceso de administrador a tu MySQL y puedes habilitar el [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html), entonces puedes agendar eventos periódicos de la forma:

```
CREATE EVENT limpieza
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    DO
      TRUNCATE TABLE esquema.tabla;
```

O bien

```
CREATE EVENT limpieza
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    DO
      DELETE FROM esquema.tabla WHERE creacion < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Sigue siendo una suerte de cronjob, pero al menos se ejecuta internamente.

Comment: hola, como puedo habilitar el event scheduler? desde phpmyadmin? o consola?

Comment: Debiera bastar añadir `event_scheduler=ON` a tu archivo de configuración de mysql (my.ini o my.cnf) y reiniciar el servicio. Desde phpmyadmin no me consta que puedas activarlo, pero puedes probar si te acepta encenderlo temporalmente ejecutando: `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

Comment: listo desde phpmyadmin me fue posible, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ojo que lo que seteaste en PHPMyAdmin va a durar hasta que se reinicie el servicio.

Comment: vale, gracias por el dato, aun asi tambien lo habilite por el my.ini