# ¿Cómo puedo insertar/actualizar datos en MySQL periodicamente con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero actualizar mi base de datos MySQL cada X horas.

Por ejemplo, tengo un campo tipo INT cuyo valor es 1000 y quiero restarle 100 unidades cada 8 horas, ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Actualmente estoy trabajado en servidor local XAMPP.

Comment: Podrías crear un "_Cron Job_" (la forma cambia si estas bajo `Windows` o `Linux`) o si online tienes `CPanel` o `IIS`

Comment: De acuerdo con @MarcosGallardo la mejor manera de todas es no complicarse y crear un CronJob. Si estás en Macos puedes usar automator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitarás hacer cuatro cosas:

- Shellscript
- Batch script
- Tu script en PHP
- Programador de tareas de Windows.

**NOTA:** Hay que tener especial cuidado con las rutas.

Tendrás que hacer tu batch script llamado **script.bat** . El cual llamara a php.exe (Tienes que buscar la ruta del ejecutable de PHP) para poder correr tu script en PHP. En este caso mi script se llama **my_process.php**

```
"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.exe" -f "C:\wamp\www\website\my_process.php"
```

Despúes, crearás tu shellscript de la siguiente manera, se llamará **shellscript.vbs** (Recuerda que tienes que ingresar TU ruta de tu batch script).

```
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\path\to\script\script.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

A partir de aquí, ya estamos listos para configurar el Programador de Tareas de Windows para que corra nuestro shellscript periódicamente.

1. Busca el Programador de Tareas en Windows.
2. Ve a la pestaña de 'Acción' y da clic en 'Crear tarea...'
3. En la pestaña de 'General', llena los campos de Nombre y Descripción.
4. En la pestaña de 'Desencadenadores', presiona el botón 'Nuevo'.
5. Aquí todo depende de ti. Selecciona el periodo de tiempo que se ejecutara tu script PHP. Acepta tu configuración.
6. En la pestaña de 'Acciones', presiona el botón de 'Nuevo'.
7. Selecciona la acción de 'Iniciar un programa'.
8. Ingresa la ruta de tu **shellscript.vbs**
9. Puedes ingresar argumentos acerca de la acción (Opcional).

Con esto, ya podrías ejecutar tu script periodicamente.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el [EVENT SCHEDULER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) de MySQL

Como referencia, hace un tiempo [respondí una duda similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50851/eliminar-registro-24hrs-despues-de-creado/50854#50854), pero resumo lo importante:

- El event scheduler es una suerte de cronjob interno de MySQL
- Puede activarse seteando `event_scheduler=ON` en el archivo de configuración de mysql (my.ini o my.cnf) y reiniciando el servicio
- Puede activarse temporalmente con la sentencia `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON` y eso durará hasta que se reinicie el servicio.

Para tu caso de uso puntual, puedes crear un evento como:

```
CREATE EVENT disminuye
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 8 HOUR
DO
  UPDATE miesquema.mitabla SET campo=campo-100;
```